# Передача данных между php и js

Tags: json, php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно передать данные от php файлу к js скрипту. 
То есть при генерации страницы php формирует массив, и js должен с ним работать.
Правильно ли в  тег `<script>` писать этот массив в json формате или есть более правильный метод это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы порекомендовал сделать примерно так:

> ```
> <?php
>      $xdata = array(
>           'foo'    => 'bar',
>           'baz' => array('green','blue')
>      );
> ?>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     var xdata = <?php echo json_encode($xdata); ?>;
>
>     alert(xdata['foo']);
>     alert(xdata['baz'][0]);
>
>     // Dot notation can be used if key/name is simple:
>     alert(xdata.foo);
>     alert(xdata.baz[0]);
> </script>
> ```

Также данные с сервера можно получить с помощью AJAX, такой вариант будет наиболее правильным.